# SQLiteReadOnlyDatabaseException: attempt to write a readonly database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, readonly

Just changed my data that are hard-code into database to using SQLite Database Browser. Before I changed all my query works fine but errors occurs when I changed. I can't do those query anymore. The database can only read but not write. I was trying to insert an entry when customer order food into table "Bill" but failed. my database file is at assets/Restaurantdb.sql

One more strange discovery is that I uninstall the whole thing and change some food name in my "FOOD"table (like Burger to Burger1), it show Burger instead of Burger1.

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
This is my lastest code but it endup got this new error. My database file in assets folder named "Restaurantdb.
Error: No such table Food when retrieve name from food.
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
 package com.restaurant.sesame;


  import java.io.FileOutputStream;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.io.InputStream;
  import java.io.OutputStream;
  import android.content.ContentValues;
  import android.content.Context;
  import android.database.Cursor;
  import android.database.SQLException;
  import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
  import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
  import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
  import android.util.Log;
  import android.widget.Toast;

public class Restaurant {
  public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
  public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
  public static final String KEY_DETAIL = "detail";
  public static final String KEY_PRICE = "price";


private static String DATABASE_NAME ="Restaurantdb";
private static String DATABASE_TABLE ="Food";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.restaurant.sesame/databases/";

private static SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;
private static Context myContext;
private DBHelper ourHelper;

private static class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);


    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if(dbExist){
            //do nothing - database already exist
        }else{

            //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
               //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {

                copyDataBase();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                throw new Error("Error copying database");

            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase(){

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try{
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        }catch(SQLiteException e){

            /* database does't exist yet. */

        }

        if(checkDB != null){

            checkDB.close();

        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
     * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
     * This is done by transfering bytestream.
     * */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

        //Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

        //Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        //Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

        //Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        ourDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {

            if(ourDatabase != null)
                ourDatabase.close();

            super.close();

    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }



}

public Restaurant(Context c)
{   
    myContext = c;

    DBHelper helper = new DBHelper (myContext);
    this.ourDatabase = helper.getWritableDatabase();
}

public Restaurant open() throws SQLException
{
    ourHelper = new DBHelper (myContext);

     try {

         ourHelper.createDataBase();

    } catch (IOException ioe) {

        throw new Error("Unable to create database");

    }

    try {

        ourHelper.openDataBase();

    }catch(SQLException sqle){

        throw sqle;

    }
    return this;
}

public void close()
{
    ourHelper.close();
}



public String[] getWantedInfos(String KEY_WANTED){
     String[]columns = new String[]{KEY_WANTED};
     Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
     String [] wanted = new String[c.getCount()] ;
     int i = 0, 
         iWanted = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_WANTED);

     for(c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext())
        {   
            wanted[i] = c.getString(iWanted);
            ++i;
        }
     return wanted;
}

public String getOneInfo(String id, String info)
{
    Log.w("my app", "IN getOneInfo TOP!!!!");
    String [] columns = new String [] {id,info};    

    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID + " = "+ id, null, null, null, null);
    Log.w("getOneInfo", "IN getOneInfo after query!!!!");
    String result ="";
    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(id);
    int iInfo = c.getColumnIndex(info);

    if(c!=null){
        c.moveToFirst();
        result =c.getString(iInfo);
        return result;
    }
    return null;

}

public String getBillInfo(String name, String info)
{
    Log.w("getBillInfo", "IN getBillInfo TOP!!!!");
    String [] columns = new String [] {KEY_NAME,info};  
    Log.w("getBillInfo ","pass in"+ name);
    Log.w("getBillInfo", "pass in"+info);
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query("Bill", columns, "name = '"+ name+ "'", null, null, null, null);
    Log.w("getBillInfo", "IN getBillInfo after query!!!!");
    String result ="";

    int iInfo = c.getColumnIndex(info);
    Log.w("getBillInfo", "IN getBillInfo before loop!!!!");

    for(c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext())
    {   
        Log.w("getBillInfo", "IN getBillInfo inside loop!!!!");
        c.moveToFirst();
        result =c.getString(iInfo);
        Log.w("getBillInfo", "IN getBillInfo XXXXnull!!!!");
        Log.w("getBillInfo", "quantity in bill is ==>"+result);
        return result;
    }
    Log.w("getBillInfo", "IN getBillInfo null!!!!");
    return "0";

}
public String getBillTotal()
{
    Log.w("Bill Total", "YYYY33333");
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery(
            "SELECT SUM(total)as total FROM Bill", null);
    Log.w("Bill Total", "YYYY4444");
    String result ="";
    int iInfo = c.getColumnIndex("total");
    Log.w("Bill Total", "YYYY5555");
    if(c!=null){
        c.moveToFirst();
        result =c.getString(iInfo);
        return result;
    }
    return "0.00";

}

public String getBillData()
{
    Log.w("my app", "IN getData TOP!!!!");
    String [] columns = new String [] {"_id","name","price","quantity","total"};    

    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query("Bill", columns, null, null, "name", null, null);
    String result ="";
    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex("_id");
    int iName = c.getColumnIndex("name");
    int iPrice = c.getColumnIndex("price");
    int iQuantity = c.getColumnIndex("quantity");
    int iTotal = c.getColumnIndex("total");
    Log.w("my app", "IN getData MIDDLE!!!!");
    int i = 1;
    for(c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext())
    {
        result = result + Integer.toString(i)+"\t" +
                          c.getString(iName) + "\t" +
                          c.getString(iPrice) +"\t" +
                          c.getString(iQuantity) + "\t" +
                          c.getString(iTotal) + "\n";
        i++;
    }
    Log.w("my app", "IN getData END!!!!");
    return result;

}
 public long createOrderEntry(int id, int quantityItem)
 {
     String [] columns = new String [] {KEY_ROWID,KEY_NAME,KEY_PRICE};
     Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID + "=" + Integer.toString(id) , null, null, null, null);

     if(c!= null)
     {
         ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
         c.moveToFirst();
         String nameItem = c.getString(1);
         double priceItem = c.getDouble(2);
         double totalItem = priceItem *quantityItem;
         cv.put("name", nameItem);
         cv.put("price", priceItem);
         cv.put("quantity", quantityItem);
         cv.put("total", totalItem);

         return ourDatabase.insert("Bill", null, cv);

     }
     return 0;
 }

 public boolean deleteOrderEntry(int lRow)
 {
     String [] columns = new String [] {KEY_ROWID,KEY_NAME,KEY_PRICE};
     Log.w("my app", "deleteOrderEntry Top");
     Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID + "= " + Integer.toString(lRow) , null, null, null, null);
     Log.w("my app", "deleteOrderEntry 2");
     if(c!= null)
     {
         c.moveToFirst();
         String nameItem = c.getString(1);
         ourDatabase.delete("Bill", "name = '"+ nameItem+ "'", null);
         Log.w("my app", "deleteOrderEntry MIDDLE");
         return true;
     }
    return false;

 }
 public void truncateBill(){
     ourDatabase.execSQL("DELETE FROM Bill");  
     ourDatabase.execSQL("VACUUM"); 
 }
```

}

Comment: Please ignore the brown colour(comment colour). My code is not being commented. I don't why it display like this. (I try to changed many times in stackaflow)

Comment: just remove the comment form database doesn't exist yet, or the ' from it...

Comment: Use getWritableDatabase() instead of getReadableDatabase()

Answer (score 5):

`You need to make a writable database if you want to insert values in database need to` add these lines in constructor

```
DBHelper helper = new DBHelper (mCtx);
                this.db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

      public Restaurant(Context c)
{   
    myContext = c;

                DBHelper helper = new DBHelper (mCtx);
            this.db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
}
```

Comment: it is Context object like private static Context myContext;

Answer (score 5):

You cannot write to a database that is stored in your assets folder as that is part of your apk and cannot be changed.

When your app runs you should check for the existence of a database (in the normal databases folder) and if it does not exist, copy the database from your assets folder and use that instead.

See these links for more info.

http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40842

[Ship an application with a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513084/how-to-ship-an-android-application-with-a-database)

Answer (score 1):

```
public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

    //Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
    ourDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

}
```

You must change `SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY` to `SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE`, because `OPEN_READONLY` only allows to read not write.