# Android SQLite exceptions caused by firebase modules

Tags: android, sqlite, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

We recently added Firebase to our app and noticed a high increase of SQLite exceptions.
Logs:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteReadOnlyDatabaseException: 
>     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method:0)
>     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:788)
>     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
>     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
>     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1474)
>     at bkf.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:70)
>     at bkw.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:32)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)>

or

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDiskIOException: 
>     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method:0)
>     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:788)
>     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
>     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
>     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1472)
>     at bkf.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:70)
>     at bkw.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesC:46)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

In our app we're using SQLite too (multiple threads, single instances of SQLiteOpenHelper), however we don't get any exceptions there.
We also noticed that these exceptions were thrown for about 90% on Sony devices. (SDK 23 and above)

Which comes first in my mind, is a failed SQLite implementation on these devices but I'm not able to reproduce it on our Sony devices, so my questions are:

- is this a known Firebase issue?
- can anyone confirm my guess?

and well,

- what will be a possible workaround

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:
For sure it's related to SQLiteReadOnlyDatabaseException (it's mentioned in the logs ;) ) but it affects mostly Sony devices and it's not our db which fails but Googles, so I don't think it's duplicated to [SQLiteReadOnlyDatabaseException: attempt to write a readonly database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884969/sqlitereadonlydatabaseexception-attempt-to-write-a-readonly-database)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLiteReadOnlyDatabaseException: attempt to write a readonly database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884969/sqlitereadonlydatabaseexception-attempt-to-write-a-readonly-database)

Comment: It is not duplicated of this issue. We are not any SQLite in our app. it is being caused by firebase.

Comment: We're seeing the exact same issue in our app, but mostly with Samsung devices. Were you able to find a fix or a workaround?

Comment: I am also facing this issue. Are you able to solve ?